# K2 tools Archive redirects to homepage

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

K2 tools Archive redirects to homepage. How can I fix it?

There's a topic with the same theme: [www.joomlaworks.net/forum/k2-en/36125-k2-tools-archive-redirects-to-homepage,-how-to-fix](http://www.joomlaworks.net/forum/k2-en/36125-k2-tools-archive-redirects-to-homepage,-how-to-fix)

But the advice from there did not help me. It's been five years.

Does anyone have any idea what else to do?

On other pages the plugin works fine. Only the main page does not work well.

Joomla! 3.9.11 & K2 2.9.0

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take the [tour]. Good job showing proof of research, this is a vital and often overlooked inclusion.